# How to refer to a previous number by "that much"?

Tags: meaning, numbers, expression-choice

Sentence:

> Using cross-validation, it was shown that modeling at a penalty
>   value of 1.25 did achieve the highest performance. This indicates that
>   a penalty value *that much* could mitigate the negative effect of
>   collinearity on model performance.

or

> ...*as that much*...

or

> ...*this much*...

Which one is more correct? Is there a better expression to give the same meaning?

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither one.

The preposition you use is the same as the preposition you would use if *"that much"* were replaced by a specific value.  You wouldn't say

> *a penalty value as 1.25
>   *a penalty value 1.25

but

> a penalty value of 1.25.

So you say

> a penalty value of that much.

And I would also recommend using *"of that amount"*. While *"of that much"* is grammatical, I think it is too informal for a technical paper.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> ... a penalty value *of that size* could mitigate the negative effect of collinearity on model performance.

That's assuming that the optimal amount is exactly 1.25. You could also use *of that size or greater* or *of that size or smaller* as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *a penalty value of that magnitude*.